# Dismiss AlertDialog from button in custom view

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have util class for dialogs with a function:

```
public static void buildCustomDialog(Context contextRef, View dialogContentView)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextRef);

    builder.setView(dialogContentView);

    builder.setNegativeButton(contextRef.getString(R.string.std_cancel), null);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    dialog.show();

}
```

and the view that I pass it has two buttons with clickListeners.  Everything works great EXCEPT that I can't dismiss the dialog when the user clicks one of the custom buttons.  So they navigate to another page, hit back and the dialog is still there.

**How can I get a reference to the dialog in the custom clickListeners I'm creating before the dialog is made?**

I've tried every conceivable option.  My latest attempt is to make a custom DialogFragment with a custom interface but even then, the view (and hence the buttons and their listeners) get created before the AlertDialog builder creates the dialog.

I feel like this should be super simple and I'm missing something ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set `onClick` listener on your custom button.

**Try this :**

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextRef);

    builder.setView(dialogContentView);

    Button btnOk= (Button) dialogContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

    builder.setNegativeButton(contextRef.getString(R.string.std_cancel), null);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    dialog.show();

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

That's it !!

Comment: Yup.  I was setting the listener before creating the dialog and it never occurred to me to just set it after ... ugh.  Thanks!

Comment: I displayed the Builder instead of doing the AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); and then showing and dismissing that rather

Answer (score 0):

Easy. return dialog reference, collect it where you invoke this method. Check in your dismiss button listener that if dialog reference holds valid object. If yes then dismiss this dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin something like this (using Anko dialogs)
This shows list of buttons in custom layout, each closes dialog:

```
    private var closeDialogAction: () -> Unit = {}

    private fun showDialog(greetings: List<Greeting>) {
        val alert = context.alert {
            customView {
                verticalLayout {
                    greetings.forEach {
                        textView {                                 
                            text = it.name
                            setOnClickListener {
                                // Make some other necessary actions
                                closeDialogAction()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.build()

        closeDialogAction = {alert.dismiss()}

        alert.show()
    }
```